# Laravel Too few arguments in function Model::destroy()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-8

I'm setting up a delete route in Laravel 8.6.0 like this:

api.php

```
Route::delete('code-rule/{id}', 'api\v1\CodeRuleController@destroy');
```

CodeRuleController.php

```
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\CodeRule  $codeRule
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        return response()->json(CodeRule::where('id', $id)->first()->destroy());
    }
```

Now when I try a `delete` request in postman to the url `localhost:8080/api/v1/code-rule/13/` I get the following response:

```
ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::destroy(), 
0 passed in C:\Ontwikkeling\TenT en Batchcontrol\API\app\Http\Controllers\api\v1\CodeRuleController.php
on line 112 and exactly 1 expected in file 
C:\Ontwikkeling\TenT en Batchcontrol\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php 
on line 905
```

I have no idea why this is happening, when I google this I only get people wanting to pass more arguments, not the problem i'm facing.

Comment: I think, it will work if you change `destroy()` to `delete()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[destroy()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#deleting-an-existing-model-by-key)** method accept an argument `destroy($primaryKey)`, to delete model instance, like :

```
CodeRule::destroy(1);
CodeRule::destroy(1, 2, 3);
```

You can use `destroy()` method like this way :

```
CodeRule::destroy($id);
```

Or you can use **[delete()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#deleting-models-by-query)** method instead  :

```
CodeRule::where('id', $id)->first()->delete();
```

The `destroy()` method loads each model individually and calls the `delete()` method on them so that the `deleting` and `deleted` events are fired.